# Chart.js bar chart with nested array

Tags: angular, typescript, chart.js, ng2-charts

I would like to make a re-useable, stacked bar chart with `@Input()` properties in Angular. My data is a nested array.

[image: stacked bar chart]

I cannot figure out how to correctly setup my chart, I always get the error in the console:

> Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
> TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

The sample data:

```js
barData = [[65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40], [28, 48, 40, 19, 86, 27, 90]];
barLabels = ["2006", "2007", "2008", "2009", "2010", "2011", "2012"];
```

The code:

```js
  @Input() barData!: (number | ScatterDataPoint | BubbleDataPoint)[][];
  @Input() barLabels!: string[];

  public barChartType: ChartType = "bar";
  public barChartData: ChartConfiguration["data"];

  defaultBarChartData: Partial<ChartConfiguration["data"]> = {
    labels: this.barLabels,
    datasets: [
      {
        data: this.barData[0],
        label: "Income",
        backgroundColor: "#3ABD32"
      },
      {
        data: this.barData[1],
        label: "Expense",
        backgroundColor: "#E02A45"
      },
    ],
  };

  ngOnInit(): void {
    if (
      this.barData !== undefined &&
      this.barLabels !== undefined &&
      Array.isArray(this.barData) &&
      this.barData.length > 0 &&
      Array.isArray(this.barLabels) &&
      this.barLabels.length > 0
    ) {
      this.barChartData = {
        ...this.defaultBarChartData,
        ...{ labels: this.barLabels },
      } as ChartConfiguration["data"];
      this.barChartData.datasets[0].data = this.barData[0];
    } else {
      throw new Error("Charts must have their data and labels inputs defined.");
    }
  }
  public barChartOptions: ChartConfiguration["options"] = {...}
```

Its template:

```
 <canvas
    baseChart
    [data]="barChartData"
    [options]="barChartOptions"
    [type]="barChartType">
  </canvas>
```

Could someone help me find the error in my setup, please?

Comment: try to isolate the problem. What is `undefined` ? Could be `this.barChartData.datasets` or maybe `data: this.barData[0]`, also add a `console.log(this.barChartData)` and  `console.log(this.defaultBarChartData)` and `console.log(this.barData`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the initializing value to `defaultBarChartData` logic to `ngOnInit` method.

From [Angular - Input](https://angular.io/api/core/Input),

> Decorator that marks a class field as an input property and supplies configuration metadata. The input property is bound to a DOM property in the template. During change detection, Angular automatically updates the data property with the DOM property's value.

To guarantee the variables with `@Input()` decorator are updated with value, thus the `ngOnInit` is needed.

[`ngOnInit()`](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks)

> Initialize the directive or component after Angular first displays the data-bound properties and sets the directive or component's input properties.

```js
defaultBarChartData: Partial<ChartConfiguration['data']>;

ngOnInit(): void {
  this.defaultBarChartData = {
    labels: this.barLabels,
    datasets: [
      {
        data: this.barData[0],
        label: 'Income',
        backgroundColor: '#3ABD32',
      },
      {
        data: this.barData[1],
        label: 'Expense',
        backgroundColor: '#E02A45',
      },
    ],
  };

  ...
}
```

[Sample StackBlitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-t11fez?file=src/app/barchart/barchart.component.ts)